# Getting data from a form in MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

In my view I have the following HTML, and yes I know I could use an HTML helper but in this case I cannot use that because of some scripting we use on the page causes serious problems when I allow MVC to create the textarea.

```
@Html.TextBox("name", "", new {  @placeholder = "name", @class = "formElement", @id="name"})
<textarea id="message" placeholder="comments" class="formElement"></textarea>
```

Then in my Controller I have setup a very basic line to print out the name and message.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Form(MessageViewModel model)
    {
        return Content("Name: " + model.name + " Message: " + model.message);
    }
```

Name is accessible just fine because it is created with the HTML helper, but I cant access message, nothing is ever returned for it. Both name and message are defined in my ViewModel:

```
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
```

How do I access the text that is in my message textarea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should add a "name" attribute for the textarea. html elements are posted based on their names.

```
<textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="comments" class="formElement"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

In MVC ii is a good pratice to have a proper Model in a View and assign the Model properties to the desired controls such as the next example:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(m => Model.remark, 10, 5, new { style = "resize: none" })
```

The `@Html.TextAreaFor` will be rendered as:

```
<textarea cols="5" id="remark" name="remark" rows="10" style="resize: none"></textarea>
```

and will allow a correct posting when the form is submitted and the Action in the Controller is called with the Model sent by the View.